# Button link doesn't work

Tags: html, button, hyperlink

Ok, so I have a button and I wan't to link it through to one of my pages. This piece of code used to work, but nolonger seems to. Is there any error in this code?

```
div align="center">
<button onclick="location.href='/game.html'">
Download</button>
```

Thanks!

Comment: you have to make sure that path are correct

Comment: this redirect works for me... No errors here

Comment: I rolled back your change to the code because it was changes to the OP's code

Comment: Ugh, please don't do this - it breaks browsers (I wouldn't be able to middle-click your button to open it in a new tab). Just wrap the button in an `<a>` or better yet: style an `<a>` like a button!

Comment: My address for the page that the button is on: *file:///C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Website/index.html* but when I click the link it takes me to *file:///C:/game.html* which is in a different place the the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your code except a missing <  at the front of it.

eg.

```
<div align="center">
<button onclick="location.href='/game.html'">Download</button>
```

also you shouldn't need the / before game unless your specifying a sub path eg.   ../  or ../../

eg.

```
<div align="center">
<button onclick="location.href='game.html'">Download</button>
```

or

```
<div align="center">
<button onclick="location.href='../game.html'">Download</button>
```

and so on.

Comment: google relative vs. absolute url's , there is a lot of reading you can do on the topic

Answer (score 0):

1. you are not using a local server, run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` from the folder that holds your project, then access it using localhost:8000
2. if the first solution is not available for you, then just provide the full path to the target page, like so `C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Website/games.html`, which is a bad idea, because the path is not portable, it's hardcoded, and it will only work from that location.

Comment: what happen when you click the button, what is the error message? can you provide more info?, and please consider @Dai solution above.

Comment: Try going to this link: *file:///C:/testing123.html* (If it doesn't work, change the testing123) (I am using chrome btw)

Comment: Seems to work now! Ty very much! One last question. When I launch my website to the public, I will make the links like: Website.com/game.html Will I have to change the buttons code because it doesn't seem to support external links.

Comment: @JackEdwards If you feel my answer and explanations have helped you best, you can accept my answer by clicking the "checkmark" immediately below the up/down arrows for my answer. You can also accept anyone else's answer in your question if you feel they have helped you better.

Comment: Ok, done. But do you know the answer to the last comment I posted under your answer.

Comment: Also I would up vote your answer but I don't have enough rep. Sorry

Comment: what makes you assume OP wants python?

Comment: from the comments, @JackEdwards link start with file:///, and it does not need python, its just an easy way get a local server running on port 8000, you can also use php from the command line <code>php -S localhost:8000</code> or ...